# Change Number of Products Per Row Fetched in WooCommerce AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

My live search field fetches the title of the product, thumbnail and add to cart button using AJAX.

It displays the output in singular columns, which is unreadable for a large product return.

How can I update my output so it displays in rows of 4 as below? (below)[image]

Front End

```
 <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()">

<div id="datafetch">Your numbers will show here</div>



<script>
function fetch(){

    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'my_action'},
    function(response){
        $('#datafetch').append(response);
        console.log(result);
    });
}
</script>
```

Code in Functions.php

```
     <?php
}// LOTTERY start the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );


    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
    global $product;
        $product = get_product( get_the_ID() ); //set the global product object

$myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
$a = $myquery;
$search = get_the_title();
if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
<h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></h4>
<p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); //ouptput the woocommerce loop add to cart button ?>

        <?php
                                  }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `counter` variable. try the below code.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $count = 1; while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $count %4 == 1 ) {  
             echo '<div class="row"">';
        }

        global $product;
        $product = get_product( get_the_ID() ); //set the global product object

        $myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
        $a = $myquery;
        $search = get_the_title();
        if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
            <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); //ouptput the woocommerce loop add to cart button ?>
        <?php }

        if ( $count %4 == 0 ) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
        $count++;

    endwhile;

        if ( $count %4 != 1 ) echo "</div>";

        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this one didn't work for me. Still a single column but the appears to have altered the add-to-cart button layout against the price without a space.

Comment: You have to add CSS for that. you can inspect elements and check 4 products that will be in one row. Please add more screenshots after adding this code.

Comment: Ok- as I have inspected element, I can see there are 4 products and associated details per row. I am searching to find out why it is displaying in a singular fashion.